# Gem to capture clicks or make UI in terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

I made minesweeper and I was wondering if there was a gem that would allow me to make a clickable UI. If not, what gems do people suggest for making a user interface in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most popular gem for making GUIs for Ruby:

http://shoesrb.com/

For other frameworks (sorted by popularity) see:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/GUI_Frameworks